# Armory client shows transaction unconfirmed

Tags: transactions, blockchain, confirmations, rescan

I am new to btc and am using the Armory client. Yesterday I transferred some btc to wallet from my MtGox account. The wallet showed the btc received within minutes, but, after 12 hours it still shows as 'unconfirmed' in my Armory wallet, so my spendable funds is 0. Also, the status shows as not yet in the blockchain. So there is no block number assigned.

However, looking at the referenced transaction block on blockchain, I see my amount with another transaction, the block has 109 confirmations, and a block number. So I have two questions.

1) So it appears my Armory client isn't reflecting the block chain? What should I do? Will restarting the client cause me to lose anything? Will it update?

2) I am under the impression that it's the recipient who pays the transfer fees. I didn't set a fee when I sent the money, but my home wallet has a default fee built in, is that all I need? Can I lose transactions if the go unconfirmed?

3) What recourse do I have. I basically sent myself the bitcoin, but it appears I cannot spend them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should launch it with the `-rescan` option, to rescan the blockchain for missed transactions and confirmations.